# How to increase the size of a parallelogram in mathml correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, mathjax, mathml

I'm trying to output a parallelogram svg by using [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/#demo),here is my source mathml,please try them on [MathJax demo page](https://www.mathjax.org/#demo):

> <math><mpadded voffset="-1.5ex"><mo mathsize="300%">▱</mo></mpadded><mi>A</mi><mi>B</mi><mi>C</mi><mi>D</mi></math>

As you see I've set `mathsize` attribute to make the output result bigger,then I found that parallelogram itself did bigger but it went up too.So I set `voffset` to make it lower.The result is,lots of space above parallelogram.

I want to remove the space,how should I do?

ps:One way to solve this problem is modifying the transform attribute in the svg after MathJax rendering,which I don't want to apply.I'm prefer to modify the mathml to solve it.Can you provides me some help?Thx a lot!

Comment: Please don't post images using external sources as they'll stop existing after a certain time, try to include them directly in SO.

Comment: Please post a self-contained example exhibiting the problem. While this kind of issue can happen when the configured font does not have a glyph and the browser falls back to a random font in the system, I can't reproduce such a bad result.

Comment: This is my first post and thx for your suggestions about it. :) I've made my question more clear and concise.